# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't see SDK

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition; along with a bunch of SDKs:

```
> dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include"
10.0.10150.0
10.0.10586.0
10.0.15063.0
10.0.17134.0
10.0.10240.0
10.0.14393.0
10.0.16299.0
10.0.17763.0
```

However, "Командная строка разработчика для VS 2017" (`VsDevCmd.bat`) doesn't see my SDK. Environment variables:

```
IFCPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ifc\x86
INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include;
LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x86;
LIBPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;
```

resulting in

```
fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
```

on compilation with `cl.exe`.

Are any additional steps needed to configure SDKs for Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite unexpectedly, the problem was in

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

missing from `PATH`.

```
set VSCMD_DEBUG=3
```

helped to pin down the issue.